# Does hooking into the same action multiple times drain memory?

Tags: functions, hooks

Currently I have three functions that run on `pre_get_posts`. I call them like this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'private_groups' );
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_results' );
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'name_profiles' );
```

This allows me to keep the functions neat and separate, but is calling to the same action three times, versus calling a combined function once,  a drain on resources?

Comment: There is no reason that hooking three times in the same action hook to do three things separately would consume appreciably more memory than doing the three things into one hook. Organize the code in the best way for you and your partners, not only hooking in the same hook multiple times, even separating that hooks into different plugins can be very good approach to make the job easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you mean

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'private_groups' );
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_results' );
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'name_profiles' );
```

versus

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'combined_into_single_callback' );
```

You can just check the difference using e.g. [`memory_get_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) and [`timer_stop()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/timer_stop). Many good plugins out there to help with that.

I would say go with the first one, as they seems to be unrelated callbacks and probably easier to maintain.

I would expect that to be mostly dependent on the callback functions you run there: `private_groups()`, `search_results()` and `name_profiles()` versus `combined_into_single_callback()`.

The hook setup itself shouldn't be resource draining, as it's just three new extra elements in a global array.

What you should be careful about, when using the `pre_get_posts`, is to target only the corresponding `WP_Query` instance and avoid running expensive code blocks for all the instances.

Comment: Yes, I meant what I have now vs a combined function as you suggest.